Snap individual elements to - snap verts to *Edges* on other mesh?
Is there such a thing as 'Snap individual elements to edge'?
I know about Snap individual elements to nearest faces. This is helpful in some scenarios e.g. where you have a group of verts and you're trying to snap them to the nearest (to each vert) parts of a separate mesh.
However, there doesn't seem to be a similar option for snapping a group of verts to the nearest edges of a separate mesh, rather than the nearest parts of faces of the separate mesh. Is this correct?
I've tried the shrinkwrap modifier, but it doesn't seem to work consistently. I think maybe the models have to be overlapping for it to work? Which doesn't help for my use case sadly.
If I'm correct and there is no 'Snap individual elements to edge' function... does this sound like the kind of thing I might be able to achieve through python scripting? (which I have not yet delved into in the Blender context). Further context for what I'm trying to do is below, but essentially my thought is a script could: 1. look at any non-manifold verts on two separate meshes (I'm dealing with two meshes which both have open rings of non-manifold edges that I'm trying to stitch together); 2. for each non-manifold vert on one mesh, look for the nearest edge on the other mesh, and snap the vert to the closest coordinates along that edge.
Sound possible?
Context
I'm working on a tricky project where I am taking two human character heads, and trying to 'join' them, i.e. taking the face from one head, and stitching it onto the scalp/neck/ears of a different head.
Yes, it is a slightly made project.
I've tried a variety of methods so far but without a lot of success.
Now, I'm trying the following method which is looking better than previous attempts, but is very slow:

position both heads in the same place. Then position a sphere object so that it intersects/swallows the face portion of the heads.
use boolean modifier to cut the face portion off of one head, and then use boolean modifier to cut the scalp/neck/ears potion off of the other head. Delete the covering faces so that we're left with an open 'hole' where the face was in the first head, and the other head is left as only the face (with an open back to it).
manually join the edges of the two meshes so that the face mesh is stitched onto the scalp/neck/ears mesh. ****This is the step I'm looking for help with, as currently I'm doing it manually and it is taking a long time to individually snap all verts on one mesh's open edge, to the other mesh's open edge.

Here's a screenshot of the bottom part of the meshes, for context: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714468185704890400/1253380545728221284/image.png?ex=6675a518&is=66745398&hm=d3e191e54e1ac45d136da0181ad094685f685373fd9ea6aad46106dec671e3b4&

You can see I've already manually stitched together the two meshes at the left-hand side of the head.
p.s. yes I know this is a bit of crazy thing to do. I am taking a bunch of head models which have hair, and trying to make them bald; hence taking the face from those head models, and stitching it onto a head model which is already bald. It's a game modding project.

I'm confused, can't you just switch your snapping mode to edges?

Nope, I'm talking about snapping a whole group of verts to their individually nearest edges on the other mesh. i.e. a version of 'Snap individual elements to' but which works for snapping to edges, not faces, on the other mesh.

I don’t really understand
